# Script for collating playlist files and entering that in a command line

Tags: bash

Firstly I apologise that I am a total novice when it comes to scripting.

I am currently using a program called xwax that allows me to play digital music via vinyl records. The program is installed and up and running, although I could be learning a few tweaks when arranging my music.

The basic command for starting the program is:

```
$ xwax -a hardware device -l /Path/To/Music/Files
```

`-l` is the flag where the music or playlist is stored

The program has it's own playlist format (.xwaxpls) and I have exported my own playlist for each entry (or what the program calls a "CRATE") that I want.

After reading the mailing list there is no way to include several folders/playlists (CRATES) without listing them all individually. If I did want to include several, I would have to enter:

`$ xwax -a hardware device -l /Path/To/Music/Files/0.wxaxpls -l /Path/To/Music/Files1/1.wxaxpls -l /Path/To/Music/Files2/2.wxaxpls -l /Path/To/Music/Files3/3.wxaxpls` and so on. Of course this is cumbersome.

A startup script has to be created as everyone has different ways of organising their music.

From what little I have learned I was thinking I could search for each `.xwaxpls` file within `~/Music/SubDirectories` and create a single entry using the $ ?

So hopefully I would end up with:

`$ xwax - a hardware device 1 -l $PLAYLISTS` ($PLAYLISTS being any file with the `.xwaxpls` extension)

How would I achieve this ?

Comment: A good starting point would be finding all the `.wxaxpls` files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
playlist_options=()   # an empty array
while IFS= read -d "" -r xwaxpls; do 
    playlist_options+=( -l "$xwaxpls" )
done < <(
    find /Path/To/Music/Folders -name '*.xwaxpls' -print0
)
# remove "echo" if the result looks OK
echo xwax -a "hardware device" "${playlist_options[@]}"
```

There's a lot going on there. Some links for learning:

- [StackOverflow `bash` info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info)
- [BASH Frequently Asked Questions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ), particularly

  - http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001
  - http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050
- [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)
- [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) to find bugs in your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Use bash's globstar to get all .xwaxpls files.
Store the files in an array and put a `-l` before each file.

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
for file in /Path/To/Music/Files/**/*.xwaxpls; do
    playlist+=(-l "$file")
done
xwax -a hardware device "${playlist[@]}"
```

**Edit:** Seems like glenn jackman had the very same idea. The only difference is, that he used `find` to find all files, where this approach used bash's built-in globstar functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the input too, much appreciated !